# AWS EMR cluster - spark-submit Should you be able to run more than one job at a time?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I have a Python script that process all the data for a U.S. state. I pass the two letter state code in as the first argument to the script.

So in an ssh session connected to the master node in AWS EMR I can submit a long job like:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 1 ./process_state.py VT
```

If I go into another ssh to master and run

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 1 ./process_state.py WY
```

Internally the state code gets concatenated onto the application name. I thought that might be the issue at first. But the second submit-spark will just sit there and do nothing. With the message:

```
21/05/04 16:42:46 WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I'm not sure what to change or do to alter the behavior and be able to process more at one time.
On AWS EMR I have 1 master, 2 cores, and 2 task machines. Shouldn't think I'd be out of resources from one script. I'm new to Spark/PySpark so it may be something simple.

Comment: I guess you can setup step concurrency level greater than 1 to run multiple steps in parallel. However I guess it's supported only in latest versions of EMR. just check if that helps

Comment: I'm pretty sure the work that is being done is just one big map job. But will test with messing with the executor number.